# Particle system - Render as collection splits particles into rig pieces

Tags: animation, particles

I got this model that consist of 2 pieces. I aded simple bone structure to animate. Now I want to offset the animation in the particle system. For that I need to duplicate the rig and offset the animation. But when I turn off Particle System/Render/Instance Collection/Whole Collection the particles become separate pieces (wings, body, bones). How do I tell blender this is all one piece and render together as one particle?
Or is there different way to offset animation in particles.

Comment: You might create an object that is the boolean union of the pieces and use that as the rendered particle.  Or you could select all the pieces and Join (ctrl-J) them if you want to have them in a single object.

Comment: Will that brake the rig? They were same object but the automatic weight didn't work on two objects in one mash.